# how to make the sign-in/sign-up buttons to float right on the bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, css-float

my source looks something like this

```
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="nav">
        <a class="brand" href="#">Project name</a>

        <li><%= link_to 'Home', pages_home_path %></li>

        <li><%= link_to 'About', pages_about_path %></li>

        <li><%= link_to 'Contact Us', pages_contact_path %></li>




        <li class="nav pull-right">   
          <div id="user_nav">
            <% if user_signed_in? %>
            Signed in as <%= current_user.email %>. Not you?
            <%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete, :class => 'btn btn-danger btn-mini' %>
            <% else %>
            <%= link_to new_user_registration_path do %>
            <button class="btn-mini btn btn-info">Sign Up</button>
            <% end %>
            or <%= link_to new_user_session_path do %>
            <button class="btn btn-info btn-mini">Sign In</button>
            <% end %>
            <% end %>
          </div>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am using `.pull-right` in my user sign-in/out  section but it just moves a lil bit towards right but not to the extreme right as you can see in the twitter-bootstrap original page. Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="nav">
        <a class="brand" href="#">Project name</a>

        <li><%= link_to 'Home', pages_home_path %></li>

        <li><%= link_to 'About', pages_about_path %></li>

        <li><%= link_to 'Contact Us', pages_contact_path %></li>
      </ul>



      <ul class="nav pull-right">   
        <li>
          <div id="user_nav">
            <% if user_signed_in? %>
            Signed in as <%= current_user.email %>. Not you?
            <%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete, :class => 'btn btn-danger btn-mini' %>
            <% else %>
            <%= link_to new_user_registration_path do %>
            <button class="btn-mini btn btn-info">Sign Up</button>
            <% end %>
            or <%= link_to new_user_session_path do %>
            <button class="btn btn-info btn-mini">Sign In</button>
            <% end %>
            <% end %>
          </div>
        </li> 
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you also assist me in someother thing? I am not seeing the `gutter` thing when i minimize the page though the fluid works..

Comment: I didn't deal with gutter. :(

Comment: Oh ok nevermind.. I will sit for sometime and try to find a way Thanks though Michael! :)